# mysql and c++ connection

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, c, linux

i'm new in MySQL and i want to use a table from mysql and show it on c or c++ program . 
i'm on linux Ubuntu and i use the simple terminal for compile my cpp or c file .

if you can give me an example in this subject , i'll apreaciate .

i download mysql.h and ... and link it to the program but i just don't know what should i write for the program :) .

Comment: `i want to add a table from mysql into c or c++ program` - c/c++ is **not** mysql. Do you want to create a table using c/c++?

Comment: no . i mean i want use the info of a table in my database and for example show it to a program i wrote in c/c++ .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/show-create-table/)

> Shows the CREATE TABLE statement that created the given table. The
>   statement requires the SELECT privilege for the table. This statement
>   also works with views.

```
mysql_query(connection, "show create table tb_foo")
```

Comment: could  you please explain about input i have to put in that funtion . what is the connection and ... . tnx .

Comment: There are a lot of examples showing how to fetch a result in C/C++ , take a look to [Retrieving data from the database](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/) in this link